# LIMIT clause taking arguments

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I have

```
=QUERY('Sheet 3 (2021)'!E:N, "SELECT E,I,J,K,M,N ORDER BY M DESC LIMIT 8")
```

I would like my `LIMIT` argument to take a cell reference. What is the syntax?

The cell reference is a function. The function is `=COUNTIFS('sheet 3 (2021)'!M:M, ">"&I24)`

Where I24 is `=(NOW()-7)`

My goal is to have my query limit from a sheet of responses that are timestamped > seven (days).

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY('Sheet 3 (2021)'!E:N, 
 "select E,I,J,K,M,N 
  where M > date '"&TEXT(NOW()-7, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
  order by M desc 
  limit 8")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=QUERY('Sheet 3 (2021)'!E:N, "select E,I,J,K,M,N Order by M desc limit "&COUNTIFS('sheet 3 (2021)'!M:M, ">"&I24)&"")
```

In place of the `8`, use `"&xxxx&"` where `xxxx` is the cell reference or function.